# Google spreadsheet ImportXML error: "xPath query could not be evaluated"

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, instagram

I am trying to create an ImportXML function within Google Spreadsheets (old version, not new) that pulls the number of Instagram followers on multiple accounts into spreadsheets. I'm using Webstagram for the URL. "Inspect Element" in Chrome turns out the following, and I am trying to pull "counts_followed_by"

```
<div class="userinfo">
<h1>thehughjackman</h1>
<h2 class="fullname-headline">Hugh Jackman</h2>
<ul class="list-inline user-489110643">
<li><span class="ui_wrapper"><span class="counts_media">315</span><span class="legend">posts</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ui_wrapper"><span class="counts_followed_by">832,918</span><span class="legend">followers</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ui_wrapper"><span class="following">3</span><span class="legend">following</span></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following formulas with no success (where A1 is the Instagram handle):

```
=importxml("http://web.stagram.com/n/" & A1,"//li[contains(@class='counts_followed_by')]")
=importxml("http://web.stagram.com/n/" & A1,"//li(@class='counts_followed_by')")
```

The error I'm getting is "The xPath query given could not be evaluated. Please check the syntax of the query: //li . . ."

Answer (score 0):

```
//li/span/span[@class='counts_followed_by']
```

It needs `[` instead of `(`

Comment: Thanks! Of course now it's saying "The xPath query did not return any data." Just can't win with this one...

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much, I've been trying to figure this out for days.